# How to insert into table with specific primary key identity (1,1)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Like a table, we always prefer to make identity as primary key like identity(1,1)
That way, that column will start 1 increment 1 when adding new row.

So could I ask whether I can add one row with specified number manually, like I can add one row with primary key 100

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
set Identity_Insert yourtable on
```

Then do the insert

```
insert yourtable (id, field) values(100,'hello')
```

Then turn it off again

```
set Identity_Insert yourtable off
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can. Using [`SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ database. [ owner. ] ] { table } { ON | OFF }`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTable ON

INSERT YourTable(Id, OtherField)
VALUES (100, 'Other Value')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTable OFF
```